# Error: Table 'servername.array' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, apache

I'm trying to make it so that the logged in user enters a value into a box and then submit's it and the form stores it in the database under "money".
However when I try to do this I get Error: Table 'servername.array' doesn't exist. I know the server (blue) and the table (players) exist and can't figure out why I'm getting this error. The user is logged in under $_SESSION['username'] and $_SESSION['id'].

```
  <?php include("auth.php");?>
  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
  $player = @mysql_query
  ("SELECT id, username, password, registered, lastlogin, money, 
  callname, email FROM   players WHERE username = 
  '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
  $player = @mysql_fetch_assoc($player);

  $getmoney = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO $player(money) values('$_POST[amount]')")
  or die("Error: ".mysql_error()); 

 echo '
 <div style="
  top: 395;
  left: 99;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: show;">
  Money Received.
  </div>
  ';
   }
  ?>

  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Bank</p>
  Enter amount of money to recieve.<br>
  <form action="bank.php" method="post">
  <table border=2>
  <tr>
  <td>Amount to Receive:</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" size="20px"></input>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Money"></input>
  </form><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the line to this one: without $player variable (which is an array from the previous query)

```
$getmoney = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO players(money) values('$_POST[amount]')")
  or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: This gets rid of that error but then it trys to create an entire new player, whereas I just want to change the logged in players money amount.

Comment: Well then you have to do an update. `UPDATE players set money='".$_POST[amount]."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"`